# The ECHO command echo only show the last line of my file instead of shows each line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to show out of the console each line from a file. I try this:

```
findstr /v /b /c:" " <%1>toto
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (toto) do set co=%%a 
echo. %co%
```

Also this one:

```
findstr /v /b /c:" " <%1>toto
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (toto) do (set co=%%a 
echo. %co%
)
```

But the first way shows me only the last line of file and the second one doesn't show me anything.

Someone can explain me what's wrong in these latter and how to get in the 'co' variable each line printed on the console?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you override co. to append to it try
set co=%co% %%a

Comment: Sorry! it doesn't work. for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (toto) do set co=%co% %%a
echo. %co%

Comment: You forgot delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "toto"') do echo %%b
```